# Display dynamic Values in odoo View?

Tags: odoo, odoo-9

I'm using odoo9, I have a confirmation pop up, and this pop up I want to display some dynamic Value in it? How can I do this? Please have a look at screen shot
[image]

I want to replace Current Contact with the name of user that will be some dynamic value. How Can I do this?
Below is my view code.

```
        <record id="view_dialog_temp_login_confirmation" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">Temp Login Confirmation</field>
        <field name="model">olims.message_dialog_box</field>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <form string="Client User Confirmation">
                <p class="o_dialog_warning">
                   Current Contact user will be deleted.</p>
                <p>Do you really want to replace Contact User? </p>
                <field name="title" invisible="1"/>
                <footer>
                     <button name="create_temp_login" string="Yes" type="object" class="btn-primary"/>
                     <button string="No" class="btn-default" special="cancel"/>
                </footer>
            </form>
        </field>
    </record>
```

Open Wizard code:

```
     @api.multi
     def open_temp_login_confirm_dialog(self, **kw):
    view_id = self.env['ir.ui.view'].search([('name', '=', 'Temp Login Confirmation')])

    return {
        'name': ('Confirmation'),
        'view_mode': 'form',
        'view_type': 'form',
        'res_model': 'olims.message_dialog_box',
        'view_id': [view_id.id],
        'target': 'new',
        'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
        'context': context,
    }
```

Comment: How do you open that wizard? Please add the code for the wizard model and where you open it.

Comment: @CZoellner Plz see my edit.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a `Many2one` for relation `res.partner` on your wizard model `olims.message_dialog_box` and then extend your `open_` method for that wizard with a default value or you just create a wizard record before opening it.

```py
partner_id = fields.Many2one(comodel_name="res.partner")
```

Variant 1 with default value:

```py
@api.multi
def open_temp_login_confirm_dialog(self):
    view_id = self.env['ir.ui.view'].search(
        [('name', '=', 'Temp Login Confirmation')])
    context = dict(self.env.context)
    context['default_partner_id'] = self.env.context.get('active_id')
    return {
        'name': ('Confirmation'),
        'view_mode': 'form',
        'view_type': 'form',
        'res_model': 'olims.message_dialog_box',
        'view_id': [view_id.id],
        'target': 'new',
        'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
        'context': context,
    }
```

And variant 2 with creation of a wizard and opening it

```py
@api.multi
def open_temp_login_confirm_dialog(self):
    view_id = self.env['ir.ui.view'].search(
        [('name', '=', 'Temp Login Confirmation')])
    wizard = self.env['olims.message_dialog_box'].create({
        'partner_id': self.env.context.get('active_id')}) 
    return {
        'name': ('Confirmation'),
        'view_mode': 'form',
        'view_type': 'form',
        'res_model': 'olims.message_dialog_box',
        'view_id': [view_id.id],
        'target': 'new',
        'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
        'res_id': wizard.id
    }
```

Comment: Problem is in view, How can I get it in my view xml? Mean how should I print on view? By Qweb?

Comment: Just extend it with `<field name="partner_id" readonly="1" />` where you want it to be.